# ontimeupdate method firing twice on an angular.js app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, audio

Dear people who know a lot more about code than this newbie,
I am building an angular.js app that is a client for an audio transcription service. It is my first angular.js project and things are going resonably well but I have stumbled upon something I can't solve by looking at past questions.

I have an audio element that I am binding to the text of the transcription, When I want the text to 'do things' when there is a change in the audio position I use this:

```
vm.audio = document.getElementById('audioTranscription')          
      vm.audio.ontimeupdate = function(){        
          $scope.$apply(function(){
            // Stuff I want to happen.
          }); 
      };
```

The problem I find is that if I change the position of the audio by e.g. clicking somewhere in the transport bar, the //Stuff I want to happen happens twice. This .ontimeupdate method is somehow firing twice and I can't understand why.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: probably you not showing us the right code, show the markup and explain a little more about your issue. :)

Comment: `timeupdate` fires when the media's currentTime` does change (i.e it fires a lot of time, especially when reading). If you want to know when the user changed the currentTime by using the seeking bar, then you want the `seeked` event which will also fire when you change the currentTime programmatically.